# ArangoRepository causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, arangodb

When trying to build a Spring Boot microservice against ArangoDB, I'm getting a NullPointerException when using the repository object. This is the code involved:

Config class that loads all repositories:

```
@EnableArangoRepositories(basePackages= {"com.parapentex"})
public class ArangoDBTestConfig extends AbstractArangoConfiguration{
```

Repository class:

```
package com.parapentex.repository;

import com.arangodb.springframework.repository.ArangoRepository;
import com.parapentex.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends ArangoRepository<User>{

}
```

And the service class:

```
public class UserService {

    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository repository;

    /**
     * Create an user
     * 
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    public User save(String user) {
        User newUser = new User();
        JSONObject userJSON = new JSONObject(user);
        try {
            newUser.setName(userJSON.getString("name"));
            newUser.setAge(userJSON.getInt("age"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
System.out.println(repository);     
        return repository.save(newUser);
    }
```

where I'm getting the NullPointerException (Repository not intantiated).

Any idea?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.parapentex.unvist.service.UserService.save(UserService.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.parapentex.unvist.controller.UserController.create(UserController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
```

Thanks!

Comment: how do you instantiate `UserService`?

Comment: Can you post packages of all the classes especially service and config.

Comment: In the controller... But there wa s an error there! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just a misconfiguration in the Service class! Fixed.